# Incapaz de instalar angular CLI :"Node.js version v13.14.0 detected. The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of either v12.14 or v14.15."

Tags: nodejs, angular, angular-cli

```
PS C:\Users\GABRIEL> npm -v
6.14.4
PS C:\Users\GABRIEL> node -v
v13.14.0
PS C:\Users\GABRIEL> npm install -g @angular/cli
```

...
+ @angular/cli@12.1.1
added 235 packages from 180 contributors in 12.003s
PS C:\Users\GABRIEL> ng version
Node.js version v13.14.0 detected.
The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of either v12.14 or v14.15.

```
Please update your Node.js version or visit https://nodejs.org/ for additional instructions.
```

---

No entiendo que ocurre, porque realmente tengo una versión superior. Me ocurre con cualquiera que descargue.

Alguna idea? gracias y un saludo.

Comment: Necesitas una versión de Node LTS activa o de mantenimiento LTS activa. Las versiones de Node LTS se identifican con valores pares. Tu versión instalada es impar. Te sugiero que intentes la instalación de Angular CLI usando una versión LTS activa de Nodejs (numeración par). Más info en la [documentación de Nodejs](https://nodejs.org/es/about/releases/) y en la [documentación de Angular](https://angular.io/guide/setup-local). Saludos

Comment: Angular CLI solo se puede instalar con la version LTS de nodejs. Tienes que cambiar tu instalación de node por esta: https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.17.2/node-v14.17.2-x64.msi

Answer (score 2):

Angular CLI solo se puede instalar con la version LTS de nodejs. Tienes que cambiar tu instalación de node por esta: https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.17.2/node-v14.17.2-x64.msi

> Las versiones de Node.js ingresan en el estado Current release durante seis meses, lo que proporciona a los autores librerías tiempo para añadir soporte a ella. Después de seis meses, los lanzamientos con números impares (9, 11, etc.) dejan de ser compatibles, y los lanzamientos con números pares (10, 12, etc.) pasan al estado LTS activo y están listos para uso general. El estado de lanzamiento de LTS es "long-term support", de soporte a largo plazo, que generalmente garantiza que los errores críticos se solucionarán por un total de 30 meses. Las aplicaciones de producción solo deben usar versiones Active LTS o Maintenance LTS.

La versión 12.14 dejara de tener mantenimiento el 2022-04-30

[Aquí más información sobre versiones](https://nodejs.org/es/about/releases/)